# Parse HTML nodes using xpath to Ruby/Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Run the following, and it's supposed to return the sequence. The Xpath are coped using chrome Xpath but in `nokogiri` it just returns empty string.

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fazer"))      

p sequence = doc.xpath('//*[@id="NavFrame1"]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[12]')
```

Comment: The page _for not logged in user_ does not have `NavFrame1` element.

Comment: ok but when i copy xpath using chrome he give me a this xpath ? what be a correct xpath to get this element form table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tried with Capybara with Poltergeist; it worked fine. When I tried your code as well but, `div[@id="NavFrame1"]` does not exist. So there might be a parsing problem...

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist_debug do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, inspector: true)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist_debug
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist_debug 

visit("https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fazer")   
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(page.html)

p sequence = doc.xpath('//*[@id="NavFrame1"]/div[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr[12]')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with parsing as suggested by @shota

The actual issue is that the div element which you trying to parse is not part of the first response. It actually gets added using JavaScript.

If you see page source of

https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fazer 
i.e. [view-source:https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fazer](http://view-source:https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/fazer)

you won't find any element with id `NavFrame1`

You can also verify this using some javascript disabler extension like [Quick Javascript switcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-javascript-switcher/geddoclleiomckbhadiaipdggiiccfje?hl=en)